# How to create Node in XML file with Space?

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, vb.net

I am trying to recreate an XML file that someone in our company generated from Excel writing to Notepad. I am using Visual Studio .NET, language Visual Basic.

I have included a photo of what I am trying to recreate.

There is a node in the XML file as following:

```
<maxJobPres uom="MPa">59.5</maxJobPres>
```

what is the correct syntax to get this output in visual basic?

the line before this in the XML file is:

```
<proppantName>Import 40/70</proppantName>
```

Which I can create using

```
writer.WriteElementString("proppantName", "Import 40/70")
```

But I am unsure of how to get the first line including space, then UofM, and the quotations for MPA.

[image: XML Example]
[image: My Code]

Comment: `uom` is a property and not part of the xml tag. Check on how to add properties to tags/nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the WriteStart... methods of the [XmlWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13bc3d8(v=vs.110).aspx) class if you have more complex elements:

```
writer.WriteElementString("proppantName", "Import 40/70")
writer.WriteStartElement("maxJobPres")
writer.WriteAttributeString("uom", "MPa")
writer.WriteString("59.5")
writer.WriteEndElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

An XML consists of various components. The most important ones are

- elements (nodes)

  - elements can be selfclosing (`<Name />`)
  - or use opening and closing tags (`<Name></Name>`)
  - and may contain nested nodes
- attributes (living within the element's opening tag)

  - attributes must assign a qouted value (`TheAttribute="Some value"`)
- and text() nodes (living between opening and closing tags)

See this example

```
<root>
  <Element>Here is a text() node</Element>
  <SelfClosingElementWithAttribute ThisIsAnAttribute="thevalue" OneMore="one more value" />
  <ElementWithChildren>
     <Child id="1">Some text<Chid>
     <Child id="2" />
     <child id="3"><Child>
  </ElementWithChildren>
</root>
```

One special element is the *root* node.

I assume you are using `XmlWriter` for your issue. This class provides specific methods to deal with an XML's components. To write an attribute will need to use [XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z46xs1(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Read this for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), especially methods starting with `WriteAttribute`.